# Funcionamento da função free() em tipos abstratos

Tags: c, malloc

Eu esperava que o seguinte código registrasse os dados dos alunos, e logo em seguida apagasse da memória:

testeTurma.c

```
#include "aluno.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    aluno *turma;
    turma = malloc(3*sizeof(aluno));

    turma[0] = regAluno("Joao",123,7.0,5.0);
    turma[1] = regAluno("Maria",124,8.0,6.0);
    turma[2] = regAluno("Jose",163,6.0,5.0);

    for(int i = 0;i<3;i++) exibeAluno(turma[i]);

    free(turma);

    //Aqui eu esperava ou exibir lixo de memória, ou dar erro e abortar
    for(int i = 0;i<3;i++) exibeAluno(turma[i]); 

    return 0;
}
```

Mas eu obtenho a seguinte saída:

```
Nome: Joao,   Matr.: 123,   Media: 6.00
Nome: Maria,   Matr.: 124,   Media: 7.00
Nome: Jose,   Matr.: 163,   Media: 5.50
Nome: (null),   Matr.: 123,   Media: 6.00
Nome: Maria,   Matr.: 124,   Media: 7.00
Nome: Jose,   Matr.: 163,   Media: 5.50
```

Ou seja, só apagou a primeira propriedade da struct aluno que foi reservada na primeiro espaço de memória, alguém poderia me explicar como a função free() realmente funciona, e como posso liberar todo espaço de memória alocado?

Resto do código:

aluno.c

```
#include "aluno.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

aluno regAluno(char *nome,int matricula, float nota1,float nota2){
    aluno a;
    a.nome = nome;
    a.matricula = matricula;
    a.nota1 = nota1;
    a.nota2 = nota2;
    a.media = (nota1+nota2)/2;

    return a;
}

aluno *criaPontAlunos(int size){
    aluno *p;
    p = malloc(size*sizeof(aluno));

    return p;
}

void exibeAluno(aluno a){
    printf("Nome: %s,   Matr.: %d,   Media: %.2f\n",
    a.nome, a.matricula, a.media);
}
```

aluno.h

```
#ifndef ALUNO_H
#define ALUNO_H

typedef struct{
    char *nome;
    int matricula;
    float nota1;
    float nota2;
    float media;

} aluno;

aluno regAluno(char *nome,int matricula, float nota1,float nota2);
aluno *criaPontAlunos(int size);
void exibeAluno(aluno a);


#endif
```

Comment: Poderia mostrar a estrutura do struct aluno?

Comment: Conforme o link [inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/aloca.html) bastava realizar o free(turma).

Comment: Precisa ver o que está querendo fazer porque isto está bem errado, para te dar uma solução só sabendo que precisa, não é só erro no `free()`.

Comment: @G.Bittencourt  typedef struct{
    char *nome;
    int matricula;
    float nota1;
    float nota2;
    float media;

} aluno;

Answer (score 5):

Acredito que tem mais problemas nesse seu código - sem ver a função `regAluno` não dá pra dizer exatamente o quê (de repente até funciona).

Mas sobre a função `free`: ela *marca* a memŕoia como livre para o sistema operacional - inclusive para partes do seu próprio programa que são "pilotadas" por trechos de código criados pelo compilador C e pelas bibliotecas usadas - você não tem controle sobre os mesmos.  A chance é que isso é o que esteja ocorrendo: a memória é re-utilizada pelo seu próprio programa (lembrando, de forma automática), para alocação da própria variável `i` do segundo `for`. Declare o `int i` no começo da função em vez de em cada  `for` e você deve ver uma mudança no comportamento aí.

Mas o que é importante para você lembrar ela não faz é "zerar" a área da memória liberada: todos os seus dados continuam no mesmo lugar, exceto um marcador logo no começo ali. Então, programas que tem dados sensíveis na memória- sobretudo se vão rodar em um servidor compartilhado, tem que tomar cuidado para zerar explicitamente esses dados sensíveis antes de liberar a memória. Isso pode dar bastante trabalho, uma vez que em linguagens de aplicações "reais" pra web e banco de dados, se tem pouco controle direto sobre a memória, como é possível ter em C. (E de qualquer forma, as falhas na arquitetura atual de CPU com o nome de "Spectre" e "meltdown" mostraram que mesmo com o programa em execução e acesso teóricamente exclusivo à  memória, esses dados podem vazar: segurança é um trabalho ingrato).

Sim - esse programa *poderia* dar erro por "violação de acesso" - e é provável que se você insistir em ficar executando algo desse tipo, vai conseguir um erro desses de vez em quando. Mas o sistema operacional não dedicou essa área alocada para outro processo de imediato, e não deu uma "falha de acesso" - nesse caso. Interessante pra você ver que os dados continuam na memória.

A critério de varios fatores inclusive: do seu sistema operacional, e do compilador, pode ser que trechos pequenos de memória sejam reutilizados dentro de um mesmo espaço do processo, daí você não tem esse erro ocorrendo. Mas a razão de isso não ser documentado com mais transparência é simplesmetne que **você não deve utilizar essa memória depois do free**.

Então: sim - parabéns pela inciativa de realizar a experiência, e perguntar quando não entendeu. E sim, a resposta correta continua sendo a resposta teórica: isso está errado, e chance do programa parar de repente é muito grande.

(Se você tivesse colocado o código completo do programa eu compilaria e executaria aqui - como é um sistema diferente do seu, provavelmente o resultado seria uma violação de acesso e encerramento do programa).

Comment: obrigado pela ótima resposta, poderia me informar como posso colocar formato de código nos comentários?

Comment: Creio que não é possível comentar códigos formatados, mas você pode editar sua postagem.

Comment: feito, no inicio eu estava utilizando a função criaPontAlunos() para alocar, mas com o problema tentei direto, o que não mudou muito

Answer (score -2):

Nelson,

faça o seguinte teste:

```
for(int i = 0;i<3;i++)
{
    free(turma[i]);
}

for(int i = 0;i<3;i++) 
    exibeAluno(turma[i]);
```

Comment: fiz isso logo que vi o erro e nem compila ----

testeTurma.c:14:10: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘free’
     free(turma[0]);

Comment: turma[0] não é um ponteiro, logo não pode usar o free( ).